# How to make a long sum of trigonometric functions into an list of those individual functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, trigonometry

I have a few long sums over many trigonometric functions. One of these is shown below. I would like to place each of the individual components into a list of functions. Like:

```
{{1/8(Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3])},{-1/8(Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3])}, ...}
```

but I am having trouble coercing the built-in functions of Mathematica to do so. Thanks for the help!

````
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4])```
````

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried that does not work? There is a `)` at the end of the provided function but no matching `(`.

Answer (score 2):

This is your expression:

```
expr = Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa1 v3] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 kappa1 v3 - 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 kappa1 v3 + 2 a2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a2 v4 - 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4] - 
   Cos[2 a1 v1 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4] + 
   Cos[2 a2 v2 - 2 kappa2 v2 - 2 a2 v4 + 2 kappa2 v4];
```

Try the following:

```
lst=List@@expr;
```

You get a list. Its first element, for example, is

```
lst[[1]]

(*  Cos[2 kappa1 v1 - 2 a2 v2 + 2 a1 v3 - 2 kappa1 v3]   *)
```

Hope this helps.

Have fun!

Comment: Or for this specific example `Cases[expr, _Cos, All]`.